# Find commit with specific git note

Tags: git, git-notes

I use git notes in my repository. Sometimes I need to find a commit with note that includes given string. So far I was using this command:

```
git log --show-notes=* --grep="PATTERN" --format=format:%H
```

The problem here is that this prints every commit SHA with PATTERN, even if it's not in notes only in commit message.
Is there a better way for that?

Answer (score 3):

Notes are stored in a `COMMIT`ed `TREE` that's "hidden" off to the side under a notes ref (`refs/notes/commits` by default).  That means you can process them just like content.

```
$ git grep Testing refs/notes/commits
refs/notes/commits:fad066950ba73c309e80451d0d0f706e45adf5a8:This is a test - Testing

$ git show fad0669
commit fad066950ba73c309e80451d0d0f706e45adf5a8
Author: Mark Adelsberger <adelsbergerm@xxx>
Date:   Thu Sep 6 07:51:15 2018 -0500

    1

Notes:
    This is a test - Testing

diff --git a/file1 b/file1
index e69de29..038d718 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file1
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+testing
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a placeholder for notes in the format string, `%N`. I don't know how to print the notes in one line, so I use a loop to test notes of all reachable commits one by one.

Try

```
git log --format=%H | while read commit;do
    git log -1 $commit --format=%N | if grep -q "PATTERN";then echo $commit;fi;
done
```

You can change `echo $commit` to `git log -1 --show-notes $commit`.

Answer (score 0):

You could search each note and only output the corresponding commit if
the search matches.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git notes list | while read -r note_and_commit_raw;
do
    note_and_commit=($note_and_commit_raw)
    git cat-file -p "${note_and_commit[0]}" | grep --quiet 'search string' &&
        git --no-pager log  -1 --format=format:%H ${note_and_commit[1]}
done
```

Notes:

1. Use `git log -1` (only output that commit) since it seems like you
   don’t want the ancestors of those commits

   - This is also the reason why I invoke `git log` for each commit
2. Use `--notes` instead of `--show-notes` since the latter is deprecated
3. Use of `git --no-pager` might be unnecessary with such a small format

#### Light analysis

I use Git Notes daily for my own manually-written notes. In other words
there is no program that writes my notes, so I don’t end up with a huge
amount of stuff to search through.

Apparently I only have 467 notes in `refs/notes/commits`. The command
takes 1.220s to complete (probably with everything in disk cache etc.)
if I provide a search string which matches none of the commits. So this
might not really scale if you have a lot of notes.

A more efficient program could probably be implemented by using what
[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204890/1725151) pointed out in his answer.